# Using System.Windows.Form not greyed

Tags: c#, using

I've created a windows form called Grades and when I click the Submit button, it displays the "System.Windows.Form" onto the label and then the text I've entered onto the textbox. For example, it displays "System.Windows.Form Tom". Now I've been researching online and people say that I should add it as a reference. I already did that and it seems as though that the using statement isn't greyed in like the other using statements. Please Help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Grades
{
     public partial class frmGrades : Form
     {
        public frmGrades()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           lblDisplayStudentName.Text = Convert.ToString(txtBoxStudentName);
           lblDisplayMessage.Text = Convert.ToString(txtBoxStudentGrade);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to get the text of the textbox:  txtBoxStudentName.Text & txtBoxStudentGrade.Text.  You alos do not need the Convert.ToString as the Text property of the textbox returns a string type.

Comment: To clarify the "greyed" myth: This just means that Visual Studio considers this using statement not necessary because you not use anything that will need this reference. You should really find some beginner tutorials on MSDN and learn to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text property of the textbox :

```
lblDisplayStudentName.Text = txtBoxStudentName.Text;
lblDisplayMessage.Text = txtBoxStudentGrade.Text;
```

Comment: Edited. I just copied code from the question. Thanks for pointing it out :)